# jQuery detecting first paragraph height different using .attr() .first()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the first paragraph height within a div and store it as an attribute.

It works on the first paragraph in the first div with the class `.actor-bio`.

On the second div with the class `.actor-bio` it displays the attribute of the first div's paragraph.

```
    //has to be in an each to get different values of varying paragraph lengths
    $('.actor-bio').each(function(){

        //Gets original height of the content area
        $(this).attr('originalheight', $(this).innerHeight());

        //Gets the first paragraph height
        $('p', this).first().attr('firstpheight', $('p',this).first().innerHeight());

        //Gets the first h3 height
        $('h3', this).first().attr('firstheaderheight', $('h3',this).first().innerHeight());

        //Sets the height of the wrapper to first paragraph height + h3 height
        $(this).css({height : parseFloat($('p', $(this).closest('.actor-bio-wrapper')).first().attr('firstpheight')) + parseFloat($('h3', $(this).closest('.actor-bio-wrapper')).first().attr('firstheaderheight'))});

    });
```

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

**Edit 16:44GMT 22/06/2012*********

Here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/SqzL5/2

Annoyingly my code works with jsFiddle, it must get mixed up with another "`(this)`" elsewhere causing the issue. Using defuz's method also works in jsFiddle, but not on my site grr. http://jsfiddle.net/SqzL5/1/

**Edit 11:17GMT 26/06/2012*********

Right I gave up on this method as the code seemed to only be getting 1 paragraph value. Anyway I did this instead.

```
    // Read more after first paragraph

if($('.read-bio').length>0){

        //has to be in an each to get different values of varying paragraph lengths
        $('.actor-bio').each(function(index, item){

                $('p:not(:first)', item).hide();

        });

        $('.read-bio').click(function(){

                //If class has class 'clicked' animate to first p height + h3 height
                if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
                        $('.actor-bio p:not(:first)', $(this).closest('.actor-bio-wrapper')).animate({height: 'toggle'});
                        $(this).html('&raquo; <strong>Read</strong> More').removeClass('clicked');
                } 

                //If no 'clicked' class, animate the height to the original height of the text
                else{

                        $('.actor-bio p:not(:first)', $(this).closest('.actor-bio-wrapper')).animate({height: 'toggle'});
                        $(this).html('&raquo; <strong>Read</strong> Less').addClass('clicked');

                }

                //stops the stupid # appearing the address bar
                return false;

        });
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: please make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or show the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not using `this` correctly. Try:

```
//has to be in an each to get different values of varying paragraph lengths
$('.actor-bio').each(function(index, item){

    //Gets original height of the content area
    $(item).attr('originalheight', $(item).innerHeight());

    //Gets the first paragraph height
    $('p', item).first().attr('firstpheight', $('p',item).first().innerHeight());

    //Gets the first h3 height
    $('h3', item).first().attr('firstheaderheight', $('h3',item).first().innerHeight());

    //Sets the height of the wrapper to first paragraph height + h3 height
    $(item).css({height : parseFloat($('p', $(item).closest('.actor-bio-wrapper')).first().attr('firstpheight')) + parseFloat($('h3', $(this).closest('.actor-bio-wrapper')).first().attr('firstheaderheight'))});

});
```